# citizen:/scripting/resource_init.lua:17: unexpected symbol near 'then'

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto, fivem

that my code for my fiveM server and when i try to start yo thr server i get and error that say "citizen:/scripting/resource_init.lua:17: unexpected symbol near 'then'" can someone help me out?

```lua
return function(chunk)
    local addMetaData = AddMetaData

    setmetatable(_G end
    
        __index = function(t, k)
            local raw = rawget(t, k)
        end
            if raw then
                return raw
            

            return function(value)
                local newK = k
            
                if type(value) == 'table' then
                    -- remove any 's' at the end (client_scripts, ...)
                    if k:sub(-1) ==  then
                        newK = k:sub(1, -2)
                    

                    -- add metadata for each table entry
                    for _, v in ipairs(value) do
                        addMetaData(newK, v)
                    end
                else
                    addMetaData(k, value)
                end

                -- for compatibility with legacy things
                return function(v2)
                    addMetaData(newK .. '_extra', json.encode(v2))
                end
            end
        end
    })

    -- execute the chunk
    chunk()

    -- and reset the metatable
    setmetatable(_G, nil)
end
```

Comment: the code posted presents a different error: `:4: ')' expected near 'end'`

Comment: 'if k:sub(-1) ==  then' has two spaces between == and then. I have not used lua in a long while and cannot remember if it matters, so feel free to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors in your code, the error in the title is not the one the currently presents when you run this code.

---

First Error: `:4: ')' expected near 'end'`

line 4 is:

```
setmetatable(_G end
```

Should be

```
setmetatable(_G, {
```

The error is pretty unclear because this is a fairly odd mistake, i am not sure why that `end` was put there.

---

Second Error: `:9: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 4) near 'if'`

there is a misplaced `end` on line 8 that should be be on line 11.
This error is expecting `}` because the `end` on line 8 completes the function definition started on line 6.

---

Third Error `:18: unexpected symbol near 'then'`

line 18 is:

```
if k:sub(-1) ==  then
```

should be **something like**:

```
if k:sub(-1) == "s" then
```

you need a second operand of the `==`

---

Forth Error: `:36: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 6) near '}'`

missing `end` between lines 32 and 33.
Pretty clear error on this one, it is worth stating the indentation ended up wonky and that can make seeing missing `end`'s a bit more difficult